# Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type User to Object[]

Tags: java, compiler-errors, type-mismatch

I am trying to iterate over a table with an email criteria to retrieve all the records from the table row. I am getting this error hint

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type User to Object[]
```

This is my attempt:

```
List<User> adminList = _adminDao.getSingleUser(searchName);

    for (Object[] row: adminList) {
        System.out.println(" ------------------- ");
        System.out.println("first row: " + row[0]);
        System.out.println("second row: " + row[1]);
    }
```

Please how do I retrieve the above as array elements

Comment: try this : for (User row: adminList)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a `List<User>`, so you have to work with the user object in your Loop:

```
List<User> adminList = _adminDao.getSingleUser(searchName);

for (User row: adminList) {
 //Do anything with the user
}
```

BTW: _adminDao.getSingleUser should not return a list of Users.

Comment: So can I retrieve the individual elements of the row

Comment: @Francis one User is one row

Comment: I mean the individual columns in the row

Comment: @Francis an Column is a property of the User object, so you can get The username as row.getName(), if you have a property `name` in your object

Comment: I see, brilliant answers

Comment: @Francis: please be careful about wording. What keeps you thinking that the *members* of a list are *rows*?!

Answer (score 3):

The message tells you all you need to know:

This code:

```
for(Object[] row : adminList)
```

says: "I expect that each member of that List should be of type 'array of Object'".

Which sounds rather wrong. So, you have to step back and reconsider why you put down that code in the first place!

The list is already declared to contain objects of class **User**, so the straightforward way to use it would be.

```
for (User user : adminList)
```

If that is *not* what you need; then well, why did you declare *adminList* to be of type `List<User>`?

And just for the record: this really a **very basic** java problem. If you don't understand such basic things yet, you should spend some serious time on **learning** java first. There is **absolutely** no point in using frameworks like Hibernate (that come with a **huge** amount of complexity!) if you dont understand what a ClassCastException *means* and how to deal with it.

In other words: learn to crawl before trying to run!

Answer (score 1):

First you are iterating a list, not an object array.
The for need the correct list reference:

```
for (User row: adminList)
```

*This is likely get a User called row (each iteration) in the adminList which is a collection of User object.*

Second, if you want to get indexes, use a normal for. (or while, do while)

```
for (int i=0; i< adminList.size(); i++) {
  System.out.println(" ------------------- ");
        System.out.println("row: " + adminList.get(i));
}
```

or With foreach:

```
for (User row: adminList) {
 System.out.println("row: " + row);
}
```

And if you want to print some predefined indexes, you don't even need to loop!

```
System.out.println(" ------------------- ");
System.out.println("first row: " +  adminList.get(0));
System.out.println("second row: " + adminList.get(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are trying to print all the member variables in an User object. So:

```
for (User row: adminList) {
        System.out.println(" ------------------- ");
        System.out.println("first row: " + row.getFirstVariable());
        System.out.println("second row: " + row.getSecondVariable());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop should like :

```
List<User> adminList = _adminDao.getSingleUser(searchName);

    int i = 0;
    for (User row: adminList) {
        System.out.println(" ------------------- ");
        System.out.println(i" row: " + row);
        i++;
    }
```

Here it will execute code inside loop for each element in adminList.